# swipe view pager with indicator

Tags: android, android-viewpager, indicator, swipeview

I am having a swipe `ViewPager` with page indicator but when I run my application I see the playbutton.xml and the swipe view does not work.
Here is my java `Activity` (play_button.java):

```
public class play_button extends Activity implements
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, View.OnClickListener{

protected View view;
private ImageButton btnNext, btnFinish;
private ViewPager intro_images;
private LinearLayout pager_indicator;
private int dotsCount;
private ImageView[] dots;
private ViewPagerAdapter mAdapter;

private int[] mImageResources = {
        R.mipmap.abc1,
        R.mipmap.abc2,
        R.mipmap.abc3,
        R.mipmap.abc4,
        R.mipmap.abc5
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // To make activity full screen.
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setReference();
    setContentView(R.layout.playbutton);

  /*  toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);*/

}



public void setReference() {

    view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.playbutton,null);

    intro_images = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager_introduction);
    btnNext = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
    btnFinish = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_finish);

    pager_indicator = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerCountDots);

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnFinish.setOnClickListener(this);

    mAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(play_button.this, mImageResources);
    intro_images.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    intro_images.setCurrentItem(0);
    intro_images.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
    setUiPageViewController();
}

private void setUiPageViewController() {

    dotsCount = mAdapter.getCount();
    dots = new ImageView[dotsCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < dotsCount; i++) {
        dots[i] = new ImageView(this);
        dots[i].setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.nonselecteditem_dot, null));

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );

        params.setMargins(4, 0, 4, 0);

        pager_indicator.addView(dots[i], params);
    }

    dots[0].setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.selecteditem_dot, null));
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_next:
            intro_images.setCurrentItem((intro_images.getCurrentItem() < dotsCount)
                    ? intro_images.getCurrentItem() + 1 : 0);
            break;

        case R.id.btn_finish:
            finish();
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    for (int i = 0; i < dotsCount; i++) {
        dots[i].setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.nonselecteditem_dot, null));
    }

    dots[position].setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.selecteditem_dot, null));

    if (position + 1 == dotsCount) {
        btnNext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnFinish.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        btnNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnFinish.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

}
}
```

Here is my xml (playbutton.xml):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            tools:context="com.androprogrammer.tutorials.samples.ViewPagerDemo">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager_introduction"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:listitem="@layout/pager_item" />

<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerIndicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewPagerCountDots"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_next"
            android:layout_width="42dip"
            android:layout_height="42dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_round_semitransperant"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_navigation_arrow_forward" />

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_finish"
            android:layout_width="42dip"
            android:layout_height="42dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_round_semitransperant"
            android:contentDescription="Let's start"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_navigation_check"
            android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my ViewPagerAdabter (ViewPagerAdapter.java):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private int[] mResources;

public ViewPagerAdapter(Context mContext, int[] mResources) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mResources = mResources;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mResources.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_pager_item);
    imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);

    container.addView(itemView);

    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
}
}
```

And here the pager_item.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:src="@mipmap/abc1"
    android:id="@+id/img_pager_item"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:clickable="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I run my application and click on my play button instead od going to the swipe view page I see the playbutton.xml.

Does anyone knows where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show dots pager indicator then I am attaching link through which you can implement dots pager indicator easily. I personally recommend it. with this even you can work with infinite pager indicator

[Follow this link](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/looping-infinite-viewpager-with-page-indicator-in-android-ce741f25702a#.3n44rsloq)

Comment: Thank you so much , but the problem is that I even can't view my SwipeView , I just see the xml , do you know where the problem is ??

Comment: try to run the demo provided in this link and all your doubts will be cleared